# data storage variable how to fix it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have local storage `session_storage`, how can I give to variable `digi` value `dogovor` from `session_storage`?

```js
loadCustomer(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res)=>{
      this.anggotae = res;
      this.dogovor = this.anggotae.dogovor;
      this.digi = this.dogovor;
      console.log(this.digi);
    });
    let body = {
      aksi : 'getdata',
      limit : this.limit,
      start : this.start,
      dogovor: this.digi,
    };

    this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'proses-api.php').subscribe(data => {
      for(let customer of data.result){
        this.customers.push(customer);
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
}
```

There is an error. 
This is not working:

```js
let body = {
  aksi : 'getdata',
  limit : this.limit,
  start : this.start,
  dogovor: this.digi,   
};
```

Variable `digi` is not active. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by active?, can you post how are you storing the values?

Comment: `let body = {...` is executed before the code inside `then(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert your code in `.then` function for ref you can check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Javascript does not wait for promise response from then function

```js
loadCustomer() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res) => {
            this.anggotae = res;
            this.dogovor = this.anggotae.dogovor;
            this.digi = this.dogovor;
            console.log(this.digi);

            let body = {
                aksi: 'getdata',
                limit: this.limit,
                start: this.start,
                dogovor: this.digi,

            };

            this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'proses-api.php').subscribe(data => {
                for (let customer of data.result) {
                    this.customers.push(customer);
                }
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    });
}
```